# SQL Server: OPENXML vs SELECT..FROM when dealing with XML?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have this xml :

```
DECLARE @x XML
SET @x = 
    '<data>
       <add>a</add>
       <add>b</add>
       <add>c</add>
     </data>';
```

Task :

I want to list the  `a,b,c`.

**approach 1 :**

```
SELECT s.value('.', 'VARCHAR(8000)') AS [ADD]
FROM   @x.nodes('/data/add') AS t(s)
```

**approach  2:**

```
DECLARE @idoc INT
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @x

SELECT *
FROM   OPENXML(@idoc, '/data/add', 2)
       WITH ([add] NVARCHAR(MAX) '.')
```

both of them give me :

[image]

question :

which is the preferred way ?

Is there any advantages of the latter vs former (  or vice verse) ?

Comment: I personally prefer approach #1 - it's s a lot more intuitive to me, and it doesn't require the extra steps of `sp_xml_preparedocument` etc. - just plain easier to use

Comment: @marc_s And along with that ... means #1 can be used in Views and such.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple test shows that your **approach 1** takes less time than **approach 2**. I would not draw any conclusions about it always being the case. It can depend on how your XML is structured and how you need to query the XML.

Stored procedures to test on:

```
create procedure TestXML
  @X xml
as
set nocount on

select X.N.value('.', 'varchar(8000)')
from @X.nodes('/root/item') as X(N)

go

create procedure TestOpenXML
  @X xml
as
set nocount on

declare @idoc int
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc out, @X

select value
from openxml(@idoc, '/root/item',1) 
  with (value  varchar(8000) '.')

exec sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```

Test:

```
declare @X xml

set @X =
  (
    select number as '*'
    from master..spt_values
    for xml path('item'), root('root'), type
  )

set statistics time on
exec TestXML @X
exec TestOpenXML @X
```

Result approach 1:

```
SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 63 ms,  elapsed time = 70 ms.
```

Result approach 2:

```
SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 156 ms,  elapsed time = 159 ms.
```

(Tested on SQL Server 2005.)

Comment: How can it takes less time if @PraVn answer shoes the opposite ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir – query cost is not the same as execution time and when it comes to XML queries query cost is not to be trusted.

Comment: ( just for an idea )  - how would you solve this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818115/cell-to-cell-comparison-in-sql-server ( dont bother answer, just answer in words...) thank you for your time.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Did some tests and using `unpivot` looks like it would be more efficient than the other answers. I have only looked at the Execution plan. Not tested with a lot of data.

Comment: I dont have any words... i never meet a sql expert as you are. ( and im in the soft dev area quite a long time.)... (thank you)^100

Comment: @RoyiNamir Thank you. I'm glad I can be of help.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer #2. try the execution plan and see that the first approch costs 97% where as the cond one costs only 3%

[image]

Comment: thanks for effort : p.s. 3% relative to the batch. what is the batch ? where are the other 97% ?

Comment: In my opinion, the Query cost estimates is not to be trusted when it comes to using the XML data type.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I ran tboth the queries in a single batch. 97% for the first one and 3% for the second one

Answer (score 0):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @BankXml VARCHAR(MAX) = '<ROOT><ITEM BAF="HI" /></ROOT>'
DECLARE @ErrMsg VARCHAR(MAX) ='',@XmlId INT,@TranCount INT
CREATE TABLE #tmptbl(BAF VARCHAR(10))
IF (@BankXml IS NOT NULL)        
    BEGIN        
        EXEC SP_XML_PREPAREDOCUMENT @XmlId OUTPUT, @BankXml
        INSERT INTO #tmptbl(BAF)
        SELECT BAF
        FROM OPENXML(@XmlId, 'ROOT/ITEM', 1) WITH
        (
            BAF VARCHAR(10)
        )                           
    END 
BEGIN TRY
    IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
        SET @TranCount = 1
    IF @TranCount=1 
        BEGIN TRAN
    IF 1=1
    BEGIN
        SELECT BAF FROM #tmptbl
    END     
    IF @TranCount = 1
        COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT = 1 AND @TranCount = 1
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    SET @ErrMsg = 'Error : ' + @ErrMsg + ' : ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
    RAISERROR(@ErrMsg,16,1)
END CATCH
```