# Cell to Cell comparison in Sql Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have `tbl1` :

```
   Id  | c1  |  c2  |  c3   |
   ____|_____|______|_______|_
    1     a     b       c 
   ____|_____|______|_______|_
    2     h     j       k
   ____|_____|______|_______|_
    3     t     y       u
   ____|_____|______|_______|_
```

I have `tbl2` :

```
   Id  | c1  |  c2  |  c3   |
   ____|_____|______|_______|_
    1     a     b       D 
   ____|_____|______|_______|_
    2     c     c       c
   ____|_____|______|_______|_
    3     k     l       k
   ____|_____|______|_______|_
```

I need to compare each cell from `tbl1` to its appropriate place in `tbl2` :

the desired output is :

```
   Id  |tbl1 | tbl2 | 
   ____|_____|______| 
    1     a     a     
   ____|_____|______| 
    1     b     b      
   ____|_____|______| 
    1     c     d      
   ____|_____|______| 
    2     h     c     
   ____|_____|______| 
    2     j     c      
   ____|_____|______| 
    2     k     c      
   ____|_____|______| 
          ...
          ...
          ...
          ...
```

**visual representation :**

[image]

i tried many queries... but not succeed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select T1.id, T1.tbl1, T2.tbl2
from (
       select U.id, U.tbl1, U.col
       from tbl1
         unpivot (tbl1 for col in (c1, c2, c3)) U
     ) T1
  inner join 
     (
       select U.id, U.tbl2, U.Col
       from tbl2
         unpivot (tbl2 for col in (c1, c2, c3)) U
     ) T2
    on T1.id = T2.id and
       T1.col = T2.col
order by T1.id
```

Comment: I would love to hear your idea about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602414/count-events-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2):

First you should unpivot data:

```
   select Id, C1, 'C1' as C from tbl1 union all
   select Id, C2, 'C2' as C from tbl1 union all
   select Id, C3, 'C2' as C from tbl1 union all
```

Then you can compare data:

```
   select coalesce( uTbl1.Id,uTbl2.Id) as Id, uTbl1.C, uTbl2.C
   from (
     select Id, C1 as C, 'C1' as T from tbl1 union all
     select Id, C2 as C, 'C2' as T from tbl1 union all
     select Id, C3 as C, 'C3' as T from tbl1 ) uTbl1
   full outer join (
     select Id, C1 as C, 'C1' as T from tbl2 union all
     select Id, C2 as C, 'C2' as T from tbl2 union all
     select Id, C3 as C, 'C3' as T from tbl2 ) uTbl2
        on uTbl1.Id = uTbl2.Id and  uTbl1.T = uTbl2.T
```

Disclaimer: 
  - Not tested.

**Edited** With CTE:

```
   ; with 
    uTbl1 as (
     select Id, C1 as C, 'C1' as T from tbl1 union all
     select Id, C2 as C, 'C2' as T from tbl1 union all
     select Id, C3 as C, 'C3' as T from tbl1 ) 
   ,uTbl2 as (
     select Id, C1 as C, 'C1' as T from tbl2 union all
     select Id, C2 as C, 'C2' as T from tbl2 union all
     select Id, C3 as C, 'C3' as T from tbl2 ) 
   select coalesce( uTbl1.Id,uTbl2.Id) as Id, uTbl1.C, uTbl2.C
   from 
      uTbl1
   full outer join 
      uTbl2
         on uTbl1.Id = uTbl2.Id and  uTbl1.T = uTbl2.T
```

Answer (score 1):

Do 3 atomic subqueries and use then with `UNION ALL` to get the final result:

```
SELECT tbl1.id, tbl1.c1, tbl2.c1 FROM tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2 on tbl1.id = tbl2.id

UNION ALL

SELECT tbl1.id, tbl1.c2, tbl2.c2 FROM tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2 on tbl1.id = tbl2.id

UNION ALL

SELECT tbl1.id, tbl1.c3, tbl2.c3 FROM tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2 on tbl1.id = tbl2.id

ORDER BY 1  --sort by column 1 (the IDs)
```

Comment: To be complete, you should alias the second and third columns in the first select to be [tbl1] and [tbl2].  Also, I prefer avoiding the ORDER BY 1 syntax (as it will be deprecated) and change it to ORDER BY id, tbl1.