# Count events in Sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table containing *purchases  time information*. (  a user buy some stuff...)

I need to create a time line which has interval of 5 minutes , and I need to count in this 5 min window  - how many purchases (count) were made - (*no group by user is needed*))

start point =  `@startCheckingTime`  which  has the value   08:00:00

end point = end of day. (*it doesn't matter if :`xx:59:59` or smaller than the next day at `00:00:00`*)

the table is :

```
DECLARE @startCheckingTime DATETIME 
SET @startCheckingTime='2010-01-01 08:00:00'
declare @t table 
(
    d   DATETIME 
)

INSERT INTO  @t
SELECT   '2010-01-01 08:02:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT   '2010-01-01 08:04:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT   '2010-01-01 08:05:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT   '2010-01-01 08:06:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT   '2010-01-01 08:07:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT   '2010-01-01 08:12:00'
```

so the result should be :

```
08:05:00    |   3  //in the last 5 min we had 3 purchases
08:10:00    |   2
08:15:00    |   1
```

question :

Do I *have to* create a temp table ( or table variacble) which has all the time interval from 08:00:00 to end of day in order to do this ? ( by join)

Or, this can be made *without* any help of *table which contains all possible values*

thanks.

*p.s. if a value is excatly at xx:05:00  , it doesnt matter to which window it belongs , as long as its the same for all items*

Comment: I'm not sure of understanding your question.. but, in case that it's what I think, what about a cursor, that makes select in the same table that you have (this one you're showing), changing the "where" to filter differents intervals of date ? Each select will return a count of an interval of 5 min

Comment: the timeline, is for a day, for a month, for a year.. ?

Comment: @ElVieejo from start date till end date ( 2 input params)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select dateadd(minute, m * 5, 0) as d,
       count(*) as c
from (
      select datediff(minute, 0, d) / 5 as m
      from @t
      where d >= @startCheckingTime and
            d < dateadd(day, 1, cast(@startCheckingTime as date))
      ) T
group by m
order by m
```

Comment: (unrelated) , Regarding _join  on condition_ vs _where_ : besides the same results , it suppose to be different in performance.... no ?  cause `join` is _how_ I connect to the other table , yielding *only* the appropriate rows , while `where` clause selects *all the joined records* , and **then** filters , so it suppose to be slower... am I wrong Mikael ?

Comment: Also , do you have any Blog or something ?

Comment: If it applies the where clause before or after the join depends on a lot of stuff that the query optimizer is looking at (number of rows in the tables, indecies, statistics etc), the query plan will show you what is going on. No, I do not have a blog. SO is probably the only place where you can find anything from me. Possibly something in Delphi newsgroups but not that much.

Comment: Mikael  , what if I wanted to see also all those gaps which don't have any value ? e.g. if I add `'2010-01-01 08:32:00'`  , I would like to see that between 15-20 there is count of 0 , also for 20-25 , and in 25-30 also 0 , but between 30-35  - there is 1. ( I want to see **all** 5 intervals and then count regard to this window.) In this situation I must use a _helper table_ am I right?

Comment: Yes. Then you need a helper table. You could use a numbers table that will give you one row for each row you are interested in. Use that table as the first table and then left join to your data table.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't feel the most natural, but you could get around using a utility table with the time intervals by flattening out the minutes with division.

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(hour, d) as Hour, 
    (DATEPART(minute, d) / 5) * 5 as Minute, 
    COUNT(*) as Purchases
FROM Times
GROUP BY DATEPART(hour, d), DATEPART(minute, d) / 5
ORDER BY DATEPART(hour, d), DATEPART(minute, d) / 5
```

This shows the basic idea.  Including a start time, and limiting it to only cover one day is simple.

Working [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4cf75/3)